# how to change selected item background based on page

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I want to change selected item background color of my GridView based on pages. I define a Color property in each ViewModels, then assign the ViewModel to the view's DataContext. I edit the ItemContainerStyle in app.xaml and want to bind the ViewModel's color property to the selectionbackground, so that the background color of selected item is different in each views, but it doesn't work, I couldn't see the expected color. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

If we apply styles in the app.xaml page they will apply to all our application.

I think you can do this by defining your resources at page level using "UserControl.Resources" in your page.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="...">
     ...
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

You can even set key property in the style and apply to the control like bellow

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="my_key" TargetType="...">
    ....
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: If I define the style at page level, I have to copy lots of repeat code in every pages, so I define it in app.xaml page, but I couldn't bind viewmodel's property to the element in app.xaml